# SQL finding and sorting pairs

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, syntax

Hi friends :) I would appreciate your input on this issue.

what I am trying to do: For all pairs of reviewers such that both reviewers gave a rating to the same movie, return the name of both reviewers. Eliminate duplicates, don’t pair reviewers with themselves, and include each pair only once. For each pair, return the names in the pair in alphabetical order.

**Please find link to what the database looks like**
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OtI5.png)

My attempt looks like this:

```
SELECT name FROM A, B

JOIN Reviewer ON Rating.rID=Reviewer.rID

Rating AS A JOIN Rating AS B
    ON A.mID = B.mID
    AND A.rID <> B.rID
    WHERE A.rID = B.rID AND A.mID = B.mID ≤1

ORDER BY name
```

I have a feeling that the "Rating AS A" line will give me an error, am I correct? 
I am new to SQL so all help is much appreciated! <3 (The task doesn't specify which type of SQL I should use when answering the question.)

Comment: Your syntax is completely un-SQL.  for us to answer your question correctly though, what are `mID` and `rID`?

Comment: `I have a feeling` ?? Go test it on db and then come back and ask the question.

Comment: @MatBailie see the movie ID and reviewer ID I use them to connect different tables, see link to database

Comment: Please don't include external links, please copy the relevant text to the questions.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza do you know any free online db that I can use? Currently, don't have access to one... which makes it so much harder :/  I have tried using w3schools but don't find it as comprehensive as I would like. I am new to SQL so I am sorry if this question came across as stupid or ignorant.

Comment: sqlFiddle  and rextester

Comment: And https://www.db-fiddle.com/...

Comment: Question arent stupid. The problem is you need to show some effort. Right now is obvious the task is too much for you. We can do the query but you wont learn anything from it. you know for give a man a fish thing? You have to search online for a basic tutorial so you know the basic syntaxis first. w3school is a good start. But start in the beginning not the middle.

Comment: If you weren't ignorant of something you wouldn't be asking.  So, the fact this site exists implies ignorance is welcome.  In my case, ignorance is life.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   AR.name,
   BR.name
FROM
(
        Rating     A
    INNER JOIN
        Reviewer   AR
            ON  AR.rID = A.rID
)
INNER JOIN
(
        Rating     B
    INNER JOIN
        Reviewer   BR
            ON  BR.rID = B.rID
)
    ON  A.mID   = B.mID
    AND AR.name < BR.name
GROUP BY
    AR.name,
    BR.Name
ORDER BY
    AR.name,
    BR.Name
```

To distinguish between reviewers with the same name...

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN R1.name < R2.Name THEN R1.rID  ELSE R2.rID  END   AS rID_1,
    CASE WHEN R1.name < R2.Name THEN R1.name RLSE R2.name END   AS name_1,
    CASE WHEN R1.name < R2.Name THEN R2.rID  ELSE R1.rID  END   AS rID_2,
    CASE WHEN R1.name < R2.Name THEN R2.name RLSE R1.name END   AS name_2
FROM
(
    SELECT
        R1.rID    AS rID1,
        R2.rID    AS rID2
    FROM
        Rating   R1
    INNER JOIN
        Rating   R2
            ON  R1.mID = R2.mID  -- Same movie
            AND r1.rID < R2.rID  -- Different reviewers
                                 -- Removes permutations that are the same combination
                                 -- But doesn't enforce alphabetical order
    GROUP BY
        R1.rID,
        R2.rID
)
    combinations
INNER JOIN
    Reviewer   R1
        ON R1.rID = combinations.rID1
INNER JOIN
    Reviewer   R2
        ON R2.rID = combinations.rID2
```

*(The combinations and de-duplications are done Before the lookups on the name, to make the work in the GROUP BY lower.  The outer query then looks up the names and enforces alphabetical ordering.)*

Comment: I haven't see parenthesis for JOIN. And are those allowed? I know for sub query works. Anyway you dont need it

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes, they work.  No, they're not needed syntactically when everything is `INNER JOIN`.  Yes they are needed if the OP wants a clue as to how this works.

Comment: I think you mean `AR.rID < BR.rID` because you can have multiple person with same name

Comment: The Op only wants names, the Op wants the names in alphabetical order.  Without also including the IDs in the return statement, having multiple `Joe Bloggs` is redundant and uninformative, even if there are ten Joe Bloggs' in the database.  For complete correctness it should be `AR.rID <> BR.rID AND AR.name <= BR.name` plus including the `rID` values in the final output.  But that's not what the Op asked for.

Comment: Ok, I see it now. Still will need `AR.name <= BR.name` In case they have the same name

Comment: Thanks a lot @MatBailie! Very much appreciated. :) I'll sit down and study your code so I understand it all better.

Comment: My suggestion, add one innerjoin each time to see what produce